# Detailed statement trace in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trace

A while back, I remember using a piece of code (4-5 lines), added to the `script/server` file, which would show a `puts` trace of every method call when webrick was running. The output was something like:

```
Entering: x method
Exiting: x method
```

I cannot for the life of me remember how it was done, or how to replicate it. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say, there are any number of ways to do this, from [`Kernel.set_trace_func`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/set_trace_func), or [tracepoint](https://github.com/rubyworks/tracepoint), or [rbtrace](https://github.com/tmm1/rbtrace), or [Unroller](http://unroller.rubyforge.org/) (unclear how well it works these days).

You might be thinking specifically of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050896/logging-all-method-calls-in-a-rails-app), though.