# Use define_method with method_added

Tags: ruby

I am trying to redefine every new method defined in a class and add functionality to it:

```
class Test
  def self.method_added(name)
    old_method = instance_method(name)    
    define_method(name) do |*args, &block|
      @@tests += 1
      old_method.call(*args, &block)
    end
  end
end
```

This results in:

```
stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

on line:

```
def self.method_added(name)
```

How do I do it properly?

Comment: your code is wrong. Without lot's of context I can tell you the solution. But the error is coming for the reason - **your `define_method` defining a method, and in turn call back happened with the `method_added`, again it calls `define_method`, and once method created; call back happened. So it is keep going on. results in recursive call infinitely.**

Comment: Why do you need the hook `method_added` ? Can you tell me? So that I can think of other ways..

Comment: It seems that the `define_method` call the handler `method_added`, you need to check the condition, and return control out of `method_added` before call to `define_method`.

Comment: As I said, I want to add functionality to each new method defined in a class. To be more specific, I want to count each method call.

Comment: Per the method's name, it's `method_*added*`, not `*adding*_method`. Therein lies your infinite loop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error is caused by an infinite recursion. Once you've defined the hook, whenever you call `define_method`, it also triggers the `method_added` that in turns recalls `method_added` and so on.

Regardless any clean solution you may end up to, the approach itself is wrong. You said

> I want to count each method call.

But using `method_added` will not cover several cases. In fact, `method_added` will not get triggered for all the methods that existed before the callback was created. Moreover, it will not work for all the methods you inherit from the parent class, including methods inherited from `Object` such as `to_s`.

If you want to count the method calls, you have other approaches.

The simplest one, without knowing too much of the Ruby internals, is to use a proxy object that delegates every method call to your object, but keeping track of the method calls. This is known as the [Proxy Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).

```
class MethodCounter < BasicObject
  def initialize(instance)
    @counter  = 0
    @instance = instance
  end

  def method_missing(*args)
    @counter += 1
    @instance.send(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

Then instead of using your instance directly

```
t = Test.new
t.method
```

wrap it inside the proxy

```
t = MethodCounter.new(Test.new)
t.method
```

Another approach is to use Ruby tracking methods such as [`set_trace_funct`](http://phrogz.net/ProgrammingRuby/ospace.html#tracingyourprogramsexecution) to add a callback whenever a method is called.

Here's a practical example: [Logging all method calls in a Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050896/logging-all-method-calls-in-a-rails-app)

Comment: I was enjoying your answer.. But after the line *This is very easy to accomplish in Ruby thanks to the Delegator library.* I didn't understand where `Delegator` class is used for proxy object.. Could you complete it by providing more code ?

Comment: The Delegator line was a mistake. I initially used it, but then I switched to a custom solution. I updated the code.

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful but I don't like `send` here as it calls private methods. Why didn't you like `Delegator` solution?
To clarify, I just want to redefine new methods in class so technically `define_method` fits fine.

Comment: leemour, you could modify @Simon's solution to use [`Object#public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send), or maybe better, check if it's a public method using [`Object#public_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-public_methods) and raise an exception if appropriate.  Simone's solution is especially attractive if, as you say, you want to change each method in the same way (count instances).

Comment: Simone, this is an excellent answer, in part because it provides a very good solution to the problem, but also because it will help open some reader's eyes to the utility of `BasicObject#method_missing`.  I noticed that by subclassing `BasicObject`, helpful `Kernel` and `Object` methods like `puts` and `raise`, and `respond_to?` are not available.  If added to `method_missing`, the method is called recursively until the stack limit is reached.  Just `class MethodCounter`?  A detail: maybe pass the class rather than the instance to `MethodCounter#new` (and `@instance = klass.new`).

Comment: Thanks for the nice words, @CarySwoveland. Keep in mind you can always call `Kernel::puts` from anywhere to use that method.

Comment: ...except from `BasicObject`. I got `"...in `method_missing': uninitialized constant MethodCounter::Kernel (NameError)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for comments, the error was caused by infinite recursion of `self.method_added`.
Every time `define_method` was called inside `self.method_added`, it triggered a new call to `self.method_added` because a new method was being defined.

To avoid this I had to set an instance variable @new_method:

```
class Test
  @new_method = true

  def self.method_added(name)
    if @new_method
      @new_method = false
      old_method = instance_method(name)
      define_method(name) do |*args, &block|
        @@tests += 1
        old_method.call(*args, &block)
      end
      @new_method = true
    end
  end
end
```

I couldn't find any better solution. Is there anything more elegant?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to append the method about to be defined to a list (Array) of methods so if you decide you want to memorize the methods you can clear the memoization(s) so

```
if !@memized_methods.include?name.to_sym then
  @memoized_methods<<name.to_sym
  define_method(name) { ...
  .
  .
  .
}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed something similar for an abstract test case class that defines setup (in minitest without hooks). I actually used your idea.

```
def self.method_added(method_name)
  # only override 'setup'
  return unless method_name == :setup

  # prevents recursion
  if @_rewriting
    @_rewriting = false
    return
  end
  @_rewriting = true
  setup_method = instance_method(method_name)
  define_method(method_name) do |*args, &block|
    # do something
    setup_method.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

There where two missing things in you example:

- The recursion anchor (stopping recursion with some flag, here `@_rewriting`)
- rebinding the method (I suppose it get's unbounded because it has the same name?)