# Set class variable from define_method inside self.method_added

Tags: ruby

I would like to count method calls of new methods defined in a class. To do this, I redefine each newly defined method using `method_added` hook. Inside it, I use define_method`and increment the value of a class variable`@@test_count`.

Base class:

```
class Unit
  @new_method = true
  @@test_count = 0

  def self.test_count
    puts @@test_count
  end

  def self.method_added(name)
    old_method = instance_method(name)
    if @new_method
      @new_method = false
      define_method(name) do |*args, &block|
        @@test_count += 1
        old_method.call(*args, &block)
      end
      @new_method = true
    end
  end
end
```

Subclass with newly defined methods:

```
class Test < Unit  
  def test_assertion
    puts true
  end
end
```

When I call a new method, `@@test_count` is still 0:

```
Test.new.test_assertion
Unit.test_count

true
0
```

Why `@@test_count` value isn't changed?

Comment: what is this @new_method? seems to be unset thus nil or false so everything else does not get executed.

Comment: Also, with this code, your question is not reproducable, you've forgotten to include the method `instance_method`.

Comment: I guess `@new_method` should have to be set `true` from the beginning, as that would allow to add new methods inside `method_added` without having an infinite recursion. `instance_method` is from the `Module` class, it returns an unbound instance method http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_method .

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that line to question. It exists in my code.

Comment: Updated question with complete code.

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20730304/use-define-method-with-method-added ?

Comment: @Denis, nope, it's a different question on the same code

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was caused by initializing class instance variable `@new_method` in the body of class `Unit`. As I was subclassing this class with `Test` this variable was not initialized in subclass `Test`. No ideas why it's like that but I solved the problem by changing `if` to `unless` thus using `nil` from uninitialized variable to pass the check and then assign appropriate values to it:

```
class Unit
  @@test_count = 0

  def self.method_added(name)
     unless @new_method
      @new_method = true
      old_method = instance_method(name)
      define_method(name) do |*args, &block|
        @@test_count += 1
        old_method.bind(self).call(*args, &block)
      end
      @new_method = false
    end
  end
end
```

Any ideas why class instance variable initialization isn't "inherited" in a subclass?