# What's inside my rails ./bin directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Rails 4 introduced* the `./bin` directory. Inside of `./bin` are a few executables: `bundle`, `rails`, `rake`, `setup`, `spring`.

My questions are:

1. What do these executables do? Why do they exist?
2. When are they invoked?
3. Can I edit them? Why would I edit them?

I've read the source of these files, and I've tried to Google their purpose, but I can't wrap my head around it. I'm looking for an in-depth explanation.

<sub>*I believe many of these files existed before Rails 4, just in different location.</sub>

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Introduced in Rails 4, the `./bin` directory contains your app's "binstubs." Binstubs are wrappers around gem executables, like `rails` or `bundle`, which ensures a gem executable is run inside the correct environment for your Rails app.

Binstubs can be used in lieu of `bundle exec` to run a gem's executable inside your app's environment. For example, instead of typing `bundle exec rails scaffold products` you can type `bin/rails scaffold products`. Using binstubs is more flexible than `bundle exec`, because you don't have to `cd` to the app's root directory and type `bundle exec` before everything.

By default, `bundle`, `rails`, `rake`, `setup`, `spring` binstubs are created automatically for new rails projects. To make a binstub for a gem executable, just type `bundle binstubs name_of_gem_executable`. You'll find the new binstub in your `./bin` directory.

Some suggest putting `./bin` in your shell's search `$PATH`, so that you don't have to type `bin/rails` and you can just type `rails`. This is risky because it depends on `./bin` coming before the gem executable's path in `$PATH`; if you happen to forget this ordering and adjust `$PATH` such that the gem's executable is found before the binstub wrapper, you could easily invoke the gem's executable -- sans the environmental pretext -- without realizing it.

Comment: did you come up with this answer yourself, or is there a source? If there is a source, could you provide it please?

Comment: I wrote this just now since no one else could answer it. Sourced from The Rails 4 Way, various Google results, and various source files.

Comment: Adding `./bin` to your `$PATH` is also dangerous when you checkout untrusted code which can place a dangerous binary in there and call it something you use to view the code, like `vi` or `less`.

Comment: @jerzy is a good idea to put some shell scripts in `bin` folder? These shell scripts are related to the projetct.

Answer (score 4):

A bin (short for binary) is nothing more than an application. As you have noticed, these files are ruby files, but they do not have the .rb extension and can be run from your shell just as any shell command, without the need to start any ruby interpreter yourself.

So what do theses programs do? I'm pretty sure you know already what rails rake bundle do.

About spring, it's a gem that keeps your app running in the background (hence its need to be run independently from the app). More infos on their [github](https://github.com/rails/spring).

I see no reason to edit these files, but that being said, they're ruby files so you can do whatever you want with them. One example of why you may want editing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7050896/logging-all-method-calls-in-a-rails-app).

I personally do put some stuffs in the bin folder. Scripts to connect to remote servers, or ruby scripts I need but that I don't want to run as rake tasks since they're more general  than my application.

Comment: This answer is quite good. Check out https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/009873aec89a4b843b41accf616b42b7a9917ba8#diff-1846d4882fa63eb5b1271541995cbfdc for explanation about why `bin` folder was introduced into rails, and how it is to be used.