# Directory for custom shell scripts within rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails (Release 6) web application I'll use a bash script to do some action. The app will call the script in a controller with a fragment inside backticks.

```
def action
    ...
    `#{custom_script_dir}/my_script.sh`
    ...
    render ...
end
```

Which directory I should place my script into? Is there a standard place for such custom extra shell scripts?

Comment: I just have a `script` folder at the repo root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a strong convention for this.

Maybe you can use the `bin` folder. Look at this answer as an example:

[What's inside my rails ./bin directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27584045/whats-inside-my-rails-bin-directory)

> ...
>   I personally do put some stuffs[sic] in the bin folder. Scripts to connect
>   to remote servers, or ruby scripts I need but that I don't want to run
>   as rake tasks since they're more general than my application.
>   ...

However, it is up to you to decide which folder is the best for you. Also, feel free to create as many folders as you want in your Rails application if it makes sense for your project.